# Flex Slider freezes after moving another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, flexslider

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Hi all I am using the flex slider above for my current phonegap project.I was very happy with this slider until I realize a problem.The slider is in my main page. However when I move for another page and turn back to the main page again, my flex slider stops animation.In addition it can not be clicked(touched).

I tried to use `$('#mainFlexSlider').flexslider("play")` when I move to main page again. However sometimes the slider does not work and sometimes do.

Have you ever faced with this inconsistent problem?